# How to implement token validation linked to a PDF document?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

So, I am developing a website for my university that manage courses and online activities (like panels, lectures, etc) and I created a module that sends a PDF document with a participation certificate to the people that attended to these activities, and now I want to link a "token validation" to this document and attach this unique token string at the end of this document so the user may be able to validate this certificate at my website. Any ideas of how i can accomplish that?

I am using Java/Spring + Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate QR code and put it footer of the document. When user scan the QR code user will be redirected your web site with query parameters. Now you can get URL in Angular and show the document.